# Laravel get all categories with posts count

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-6

> Hi, I'm trying to get Array contain all Categories with Number of
>   Posts in each category: Ex:

```
[
{id: 1, name: "category1", posts: 15 },
{id: 2, name: "category2", posts: 33 },
{id: 3, name: "category3", posts: 27 }
]
```

**Details:**

- Posts Table

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();;
        $table->longText('content');
        $table->boolean('published')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

- Categories Table

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

- Posts Model

```php
public function category()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
}
```

- Category Model

```php
public function posts()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post');
}
```

- **Categories Controller**

```php
public function index()
{
  $Categories  = Category::with('posts')->get();
  return response()->json($Categories);
}
```

but the this function return posts with all filed, is way to count them and add number as param in array ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

```
$categories = Category::withCount('posts')->get();
```

then you can loop trough $categories and access to

```
$category->posts_count
```

on each category .

Comment: This code works perfectly... thanks